# Error passing array to function and displaying elements?

Tags: c, arrays, linux, function, parameter-passing

C language - Linux

My program context: Read arguments input by user, passed arguments to an array after meeting requirements, and passed the array to a function. The function, then has to display the array elements. For some reason, the output is displaying random big numbers such as "-914536439" which is wrong.

User input example: ./file 3 2 5 10 6 
Current output: Array elements are 0 0 0 -914536439 .. -914536430 (wrong!) 
Desired output: Display array elements as it was given, "Current array elements are: 3 5 10 6 "

I think I made an error with my void function somewhere. How can I fix this so that the function will display the array elements?

My code:

```
/* function to display element of modified array */
void function(int *arr)
{
   int j, size;
   size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

   printf("Current array elements are:");
   for (j=0; j < size; j++)
   {
      /* display array elements */
      printf("%d ", arr[j]);
   }
}

int main (int argc, int *argv[])
{ 
   /* max array size is 100 */
   int arr[100];

   for (int i=0; i<argc; i++)
   {
       /*check if value of arguments is greater than value of argv[1] */
       if (argv[i] > argv [1])
       {
          /* pass value of argument(s) to array named arr */
          arr[i] = argv[i];    
       }    
   }
   /* pass array arr to function */
   function(arr);

   /*other code*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a couple issues in your program. The most obvious is argv is a char **. But you are assigning a argv[i] (which is char *) to arr[i] (which is a int). Your compiler probably warns you about this. To convert a char* to an int you can use atoi() in this case.
You also want to use a different index for arr instead of i. And only increase it if you found a array element larger than the first one.

```
if (atoi(argv[i]) > atoi(argv [1]))
{
    /* pass value of argument(s) to array named arr */
    arr[j] = atoi(argv[i]);    
    j++;
}
```

Another issue is, sizeof(arr) in your function will just give you the size of an integer pointer. You  want the number of elements you found, which you should pass in as a second argument to the function.